# How to transfer a search string to music apps on android from another app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm developing an app for android that calls for other music apps, and I would like to transfer from my app to the music app I'm calling a search string (For example: "Thriller by Michael Jackson").
I know that Google's voice search for android, and also Dragon personal assistant, can do this.
I don't control what the music apps accept, only what my app is sending though the intent I'm creating when starting a new activity.
Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the search string from your activity to the music app activity that you want to open via a bundle.

```
Intent i = new Intent(//Insert required action for the activity you want to open);
 // you should get the text from a widget like editText here
 String searchString ="Thriller by Michael Jackson";
 //Create a bundle
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 //add the search string to the bundle 
 bundle.putString("SEARCH_STRING",searchString);
 //add bundle to intent
 i.putExtras(bundle);
 //call the music app's activity
 startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to make the music app to present the search string (or the relevant information in it) in the search slot? It happens after asking for music using Google's voice search in the selected music app.